# Hardware Acceleration issue with emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation, haxm

I installed Android Studio and fired up the default emulator (Nexus 5 API 23), but got the following error message:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.5 < 6.0.1).

It seems that a lot of people already encountered this issue and the solution would be to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator, but in my case, it is already installed.

Another thing I read is:

> After you download it and make sure you run the setup located in: {SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe

I'm on a 2015 retina Macbook though, so this is not an option.
Also when creating a new Virtual Device, the error message remains the same.

What can I do to get a working emulator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282302/4919237

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should mount and run the `IntelHAXM_1.1.4.dmg` file located in `{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is that HAXM is downloaded but not installed. 
So you should run executable file and install new version of HAXM.

HAXM path: `{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`